# WebView2 AddHostObjectToScript can't access function with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, webview2

I've been following the documentation for the webview2 on microsoft's official website but I have encountered a problem that I am not sure how to fix.

I have added a .NET object using AddHostObjectToScript and it works as long as the function has no parameter. When calling the object function that has a parameter in JS, I keep on getting a "parameter is incorrect" error.

This is how I am calling the host objects in angular app:

`result = await window?.chrome?.webview?.hostObjects.bridge.Func("John");`

and this is from my WinUI 3.0 app:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Bridge
    {
        public string Func(string param)
        {
            return "Example: " + param;
        }

        public string Sample()
        {
            return "Example: ";
        }
        public BridgeAnotherClass AnotherObject { get; set; } = new BridgeAnotherClass();

        // Sample indexed property.
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("Items")]
        public string this[int index]
        {
            get { return m_dictionary[index]; }
            set { m_dictionary[index] = value; }
        }
        private Dictionary<int, string> m_dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }


    
    public sealed partial class WebViewPage : Page
    {
        public WebViewViewModel ViewModel { get; }

        public WebViewPage()
        {
            ViewModel = Ioc.Default.GetService<WebViewViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel.WebViewService.Initialize(webView);
            webView.WebMessageReceived += getMsg;
            InitializeAsync();
        }

        async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            var interop = webView.CoreWebView2.As<ICoreWebView2Interop>();
            interop.AddHostObjectToScript("bridge", new Bridge());
            
        }
```

Comment: I used the `sync` version of the bridge. Try to call in this way: `result =  window?.chrome?.webview?.hostObjects.sync.bridge.Func("John");`

Comment: I don't get an error, but still do not get a return value. It's a WinForms app. WebView2 runtime 96.0.1054.34

Comment: This actually works now. I had an error in my JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebView2 currently has an issue where the WinRT API's interop interface AddHostObjectToScript doesn't work well with .NET objects. This is a bug in WebView2.

Comment: Oh, excellent. Any reasonable workarounds for this?

Comment: Not really. The issue is that the code for dealing with .NET objects is written in C# and is in the .NET API unlike the native WinRT API. We're working on WinRT AddHostObjectToScript support so you might wait for that. No other reasonable workarounds though. Unreasonable workarounds include using COM IDispatch implementation or not using AddHostObjectToScript and using PostWebMessage or some other communication mechanism.